# How to sample for 3 different variables to result a unique variable out of the 3 every time?

Tags: r, simulation, sample

working on a project and i can't figure out how to get unique values every time. The program works but I don't know how to filter unique values so that the 3 strings are different any time. Such as a=abc, b=xyz, c=lmn every time some variation of those, but all unique values.

```
a = c('ABC', 'XYZ', 'LMN')
if(length(a)==3){
  b = sample(a, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
  c = sample(a[!(c %in% d)], size = 1, replace = TRUE)
  a = sample(a[!(a %in% c(c, b))], size = 1, replace = TRUE)
  }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of correct output vs. incorrect output? It looks like you're starting with three possible values in `a` -- are these the only possible values, and if not what are some of the other possibilities?

Comment: Yeah, it depends on how the samples run, but an output may look like a=LMN, b=ABC and c=ABC, but the end result desired is for there to be 3 unique outputs

Comment: you don't have a `d` for `c %in% d`, but it seems `replace = FALSE` would get you closer to your goal.

Comment: yeah d is supposed to be b, but the goal is to is to say that c can't be b and then a cant be c or b

Comment: once you have a mechanism that gives you 3 unique values, each time, what are you doing with them next?

Comment: yeah i appreciate the advice but i gave up like 35 hours too late

Answer (score 0):

In cases where the number of items selected equals the number of possible items you are getting a particular kind of sample called a permutation. The `sample` function is set up to do that:

```
> a = c('ABC', 'XYZ', 'LMN')
> sample(a,3)
[1] "ABC" "XYZ" "LMN"
> sample(a,3)
[1] "ABC" "XYZ" "LMN"
> sample(a,3)
[1] "ABC" "LMN" "XYZ"
> sample(a,3)
[1] "XYZ" "LMN" "ABC"
> sample(a,3)
[1] "LMN" "ABC" "XYZ"
```

If the number of items to be selected is less than the size of the "universe", then you can still use `sample` because the default for the "replacement" argument is FALSE.

```
> a = c('ABC', 'XYZ', 'LMN', "jrw", "wxz")
> sample(a,3)
[1] "XYZ" "LMN" "wxz"
> sample(a,3)
[1] "LMN" "jrw" "ABC"
> sample(a,3)
[1] "wxz" "XYZ" "ABC"
> sample(a,3)
[1] "ABC" "wxz" "jrw"
```

Comment: i understand, but how does that apply to my code? i just want unique results for c and a. there are 3 different values and i want to figure out how to put those 3 into a, b and c uniquely each time without having duplicates in a variable.

Comment: It doesn’t apply to your code. Your code had errors and unnecessary calls to `sample`.  If you want three separate variable after creating a permutation then just assign a,b,&c to the successive values in the permutations.

Answer (score 0):

I got the sense that 'sample' was some part of a given sequence, potentially A in ABC. But still going with expanding universe

```
set.seed(42)
a3 <- unlist(strsplit(a, split=NULL))
> a3
[1] "A" "B" "C" "X" "Y" "Z" "L" "M" "N"
b <- sample(a3, size = 3, replace = FALSE)
b
[1] "A" "Y" "N"
setdiff(a3,b)
[1] "B" "C" "X" "Z" "L" "M"
c <- setdiff(a3,b)
d <- sample(c, size = 3, replace = FALSE)
d
[1] "B" "C" "Z"
e <- setdiff(c, d)
e
[1] "X" "L" "M"
```

But I could have misinterpreted the goal. In a pinch:

```
a[sample(order(a), size = 3)]
[1] "LMN" "XYZ" "ABC"
# or
 combn(sample(a,size=3), 3, paste, sep  = ',')
     [,1] 
[1,] "XYZ"
[2,] "LMN"
[3,] "ABC"
```

you harvest three results at a time and assign them to a,b,c; then pick again.
But, to your point of testing the results of your sample(s), prior to employing further, and having a result `b = c('ABC', 'ABC', 'XYZ')`, where your `if` test is != `length(unique(a)) [1] 3`, perhaps

```
b[anyDuplicated(b)] <- setdiff(a,b)
b
[1] "ABC" "LMN" "XYZ"
# where 
anyDuplicated(b)
[1] 2
 # give the index of the duplicated value in b and 
setdiff(a,b)
[1] "LMN"
# give the unique value missing in b, note (a before b)
```

All this just says test your sample results `b`against your unique template `a` prior to picking apart b into a,b,c, then adjust as necessary. Seems more straightforward.

Comment: no the strings are attached, the problem i was having was with [!(c %in% b)] to try and filter unique results for each string into each variable